# How to pass JSON data from ejs to normal inline javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

Can you please help me out I am making a simple CRUD project. From node js, I am getting data in JSON format. But I want to transfer that JSON data from EJS to normal inline javascript. Can anyone please help me out with this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some of your codes and setups so we can better help you?

Answer (score 0):

Which json you are rendering to ejs file you can access it in this way.

```
router.get("/csv_edit",admin_auth, (req, res) => {
res.render("admin-dashboard", {
    page: {
        name: "edit-csv-main",
        csvId: req.query.csv_id,
        ip: req.ipInfo.ip
    }
});
```

});

In your javascript file

```js
let r = <%- page %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How'bout something like...

In nodejs...

```
res.render('mytemplate', { arrayOfRecs });
```

In views/mytemplate.ejs...

```
<%
    arrayOfRecs.forEach(rec => {
        console.log('This is rec: ', rec);
    });
%>
```